# Automatic creation of listed users & groups with accompanied UID/GIDs based on system's hostname

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

My objective is to automatically create a list of users and groups with their accompanied UID/GIDs based on the hostname of the system. I'm adding this script to the %post section of a kickstart configuration in which the listed users and groups with accompanied UID/GIDs will be created based on the hostname of the system that the kickstart is being executed on. I think that the best approach would be to hardcode the user/group combinations into an associative array similar to:
`declare -A groups`
`groups[user1]='group1,group2'` 
`groups[user2]='group1,group2'` 
`groups[user3]='group1,group2'`

The problem is that the hardcoded list of combinations should be setup by the system's hostname something like this:

```
declare -A groups
groups[hostname1]='user1:group1,group2' 'user2:group1,group2' etc.
groups[hostname2]='user1:group1,group2' 'user2:group1,group2' etc.
groups[hostname3]='user1:group1,group2' 'user2:group1,group2' etc.
```

The problem with this is that the UIDs/GIDs also need to be added to some portion of the array or have another array with the UID/GID combinations hardcoded. Should I setup a separate array with the UIDs/GIDs of each user/group? Any suggestions or recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thank you.